# How do I choose which .cpp file to run in XCode?

Tags: c++, xcode

I've seen some responses to things like this, but I'm still not sure what to do. I'm proficient in Java with Eclipse, and am starting C++ with XCode. I'm using a textbook, so I'd like to organize my workspace with one .cpp file for each chapter, but when I do this and try to run one of the files, it always defaults to the first one. How can I have multiple .cpp files in a workspace and run different ones? This might be a fundamentally different thing than in java where you could just select the class, and if it had a main method run it from there, but any help would be appreciated. My workspace setup currently looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOVNM.png

Comment: In [tag:c++] you'll need a `main()` function to run, you can't choose an arbitrary class or function to _'run'_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What πάντα ῥεῖ says is right. To put it more bluntly, you probably don't want a single Xcode project with a different .cpp file per chapter of your text. (You can do it that way, but it involves a bunch of setup that will be confusing to you as a newbie with C++ and Xcode.) It would probably be easier if you made a separate Xcode project for each chapter.